# How to add a validation to rails model which depends on another model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Can't find a best way of getting this done easily
I want to come up with database model for the following problem.

There is a Deal table which has one associated account table. Each account can have many contacts. Now one deal need to assign a primary contact which must be one among the many contacts of the associated account. How to make sure that the primary contact is one of the account contacts.

```
Deal Table
  account_id
  primary_contact_id

Account Table
  name and other params

Contact Table
  account_id
  phone, email etc.
```

Eg. class which I use currently

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :contact
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
  has_many :deals
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :deals
end
```

I can add validation in deal model or controller to make sure that contact getting added is one among its account contacts. But how to take care of following cases:

1. Deleting a contact from an account should make sure that corresponding contact_id of the deal table is set to nil
2. Deleting an account associated with a deal should make sure that contact_id of that deal table is nullified
3. Updating an account association should make sure that contact_id of the deal is nullified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you could use model callbacks, e.g.:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :contact

  before_update :nullify_contact_association, :if => lambda{|i| i.account_id_changed?}

  private
  # Nullify contact_id of the deal if it's account association was changed
  def nullify_contact_association
    self.contact_id = nil
  end
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
  has_many :deals

  before_destroy :nullify_dependencies

  private

  #Deleting an account associated with a deal should
  #make sure that contact_id of that deal table is nullified
  def nullify_dependencies
    self.deals.update_all(:contact_id => nil) if deal.present?
  end
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :deals

  before_destroy :nullify_dependencies

  private

  #Deleting a contact from an account should make sure
  #that corresponding contact_id of the deal table is set to nil
  def nullify_dependencies
    self.deals.update_all(:contact_id => nil) if account.present?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Deal

  validate :contact_is_among_the_contacts_in_associated_account

  private

  def contact_is_among_the_contacts_in_associated_account
    errors.add(:contact_id, "Your error message") unless contact.in?(account.contacts)
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it this way, but the problem is with one of the questions I've asked above
Suppose deal with id 1 has account_id 1, which has contacts with ids 1 and 2. Now I'm assigning deal primary contact as contact 2. After that if we remove contact 2 from contacts table, deal table will remain to have account_id 1 and primary_contact_id as 2. This could've ignored since deal.primary_contact returns nil and it's fine. But issue is that now we won't be able to do any other edits(like name change) to the deal, because all further edits will be prevented by this validation.

Comment: probably I can solve this issue by making sure that primary_contact_id is set to nil whenever a contact with that id gets deleted from the db. Also I've to make sure primary_contact_id and account_id will be nullified whenever an account gets deleted. How to achieve this in rails?